# Load child object records with filter condition in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

Designed the Data Access Layer with Entity Framework and the Sample POCO Structure of PackageInstance object is

```
public class PackageInstance
{
  public virtual long PackageInstanceId {set;get;}
  public virtual boolean IsDeleted {set;get;}
  public virtual List<Session> Sessions {set;get;}
}

public class Session
{
  public virtual long SessionId {set;get;}
  public virtual long PackageInstanceId {set;get;}
  public virtual boolean IsDeleted {set;get;}
  public virtual List<Note> Notes {set;get;}
}

public class Note
{
  public virtual long NoteId {set;get;}
  public virtual long SessionId {set;get;}
  public virtual boolean IsDeleted {set;get;}
  public virtual List<Documents> Document {set;get;}
}
```

I need to load PackageInstance object along with his child objects in single method call, instead of loading each object separately.

```
  var packageInstanceDB = entity.PackageInstances.First(p => p.PurchaseSessionId == purhcaseSessionId);                   
  //There is a DB call happening here to load the Session.
  packageInstanceDB.Sessions.Where(s=>!s.IsActive).ForEach(s => 
  {
       //Again there is a DB call happening here to load the associated session notes.
       s.Notes.Where(sn => !sn.IsDeleted).ToList().ForEach(sd=>
       //Again there is a DB call happening here to load the associated note documents.
       sd.Documents.Where(doc=>!doc.IsDeleted));
  });
```

Here how to eliminate the multiple DB calls?

Comment: Your code is complied?

Comment: Cuong Le. Updated the question with actual code snap. There is multiple DB call is also happening here.

Comment: Can you show us an example and explain that what you would like to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

EF+ Query IncludeFilter feature allow filtering related entities. It support EF5

```
var packageInstanceDB = entity.PackageInstances
    .IncludeFilter(x => x.Sessions)
    .IncludeFilter(x => x.Sessions.Select(y => y.Notes.Where(sn => !sn.IsDeleted)))
    .IncludeFilter(x => x.Sessions.SelectMany(y => y.Notes.Where(sn => !sn.IsDeleted)).Select(z => z.Documents.Where(sn => !sn.IsDeleted)))
    .First(p => p.PackageInstanceId == purhcaseSessionId);
```

*Note: Every path must be included*

Wiki: [EF+ Query IncludeFilter](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter)

Comment: First of all Kudos to Jonathan Magnan... Before 4 months I replaced the existing code with EFP and it gave better performance.....